# How to switch applications/windows in 11.10 as in 11.04?

Tags: 11.10, shortcut-keys

I just upgraded to Ubuntu 11.10. To switch among applications by `Alt+Tab`, it is a little bit different from Ubuntu 11.04. It groups same kind of windows, for instance it puts `Emacs` into 1 icon, `Adobe reader` in 1 icon. So when I have several windows of same kind, it is not easy to search for a specific one just by `Alt+Tab`. In 11.04, it is much easier...

Does anyone know how to overcome it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I revert Alt-tab behavior changed in 11.10?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/68151/how-do-i-revert-alt-tab-behavior-changed-in-11-10)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To switch between windows of the same kind, you use alt+the button above tab. When you have alt+tab open, you can also press the down arrow key to show the open windows as previews. It's mostly the same as the before mentioned.