# How can I set that Alt-TAB to switch windows only on the current workspace?

Tags: unity, shortcut-keys, window-manager

How can I set Alt-TAB shortcut to switch only between current workspace windows (not all windows on all workspaces) used Unity in 11.10?
I set a plugin for it in compiz manager, but it could not solve my problem. Thx!

Comment: I don'ẗ understand the question. What do you mean "actual desktop applications"?

Comment: desktop means workspace, sorry :)

Comment: but, I think, I found the solution. In compiz manager in the Ubuntu Unity Plugin in the 'Switcher' tab the 'Key to start switcher' has to be disabled. And after one of application switcher plugin has to be enabled.

Comment: THIS IS DUPLICATE OF:

http://askubuntu.com/questions/68151/how-do-i-revert-alt-tab-behavior-to-switch-between-windows-on-the-current-worksp

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In compiz manager in the **Ubuntu Unity Plugin** in the **Switcher** tab the ***Key to start switcher*** has to be **disabled**. And after one of **application switcher** plugin has to be **enabled**.

Comment: I would propose the **Static Application Switcher**