# How do I disable application groupin in Ubuntu 11.10 ALT + TAB application switcher?

Tags: 11.10, application-switcher

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Revert Alt-tab behavior changed in 11.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68151/revert-alt-tab-behavior-changed-in-11-10)

In Ubuntu 11.10 the ALT + TAB application switcher shows the applications grouped by executable apparently. I find it very annoying that I have to take an extra step when switching between windows with that are grouped (for example two instances of an IDE or anything else like that).

Is there any way to ungroup the applications in the switcher and have it show one icon per window?

I've looked among the settings and google without luck. Seems like I"me the only one annoyed by this issue.