# Switch between applications in the current workspace

Tags: 11.10, unity, compiz

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I revert Alt-tab behavior to switch between windows on the current workspace?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68151/how-do-i-revert-alt-tab-behavior-to-switch-between-windows-on-the-current-worksp)

With Alt+Tab I can switch between all my applications.
But do you know how to switch between the applications **only in the current workspace**?

Thanks!

Comment: What window manager are you using?