# Ungroup with alt tab

Tags: compiz, application-switcher

I have a "serious" issue.

I use Ubuntu 11.10 and I really like it. There's just one thing that drives me crazy.

Can someone tell me how I can ungroup for ex. Mozilla with alt tab? I've already downloaded CompizConfig but I cannot unveil this secret. I've searched many forums but I seem to be the only one not understanding this.. :(

Comment: What do you mean by "ungroup"?

Comment: @root45 I believe he means to switch between windows of the same application as 11.10 shows them as one "app" when alt-tabbing

Comment: Possible duplicate answer to http://askubuntu.com/questions/68151/revert-alt-tab-behavior-changed-in-11-10

Answer (score 11):

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>~</kbd> will allow you to switch between windows of the same app. i don't know how to turn it off permanently, but it will allow you to navigate them.

Additional hint: 
 I have a German keyboard and a German Keyboard layout.
Nevertheless the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>~</kbd> works with the same key where the English keyboard has, so for German users it is <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>^</kbd> .

Answer (score 2):

In the "Window Management" section of CompizConfig Settings Manager(CCSM) there are a few window switcher options that have the "All windows" feature. **Application Switcher** is a basic 2d switcher while **Ring Switcher** and **Shift Switcher** offer more eye candy. Whichever one you pick, remember to set hot keys for the bindings marked "All windows".

[image: CCSM window management]

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you means for "ungroup"... in a "standard" configuration

the "secret" is... Super button! (the one beetwen Ctrl and Alt)

alt+tab → alt+Super → alt+tab

bye

Comment: This doesn't work, the keybinding is ALT + `