# Unity: How can I make Alt+TAB browse through all my windows without grouping them?

Tags: unity, shortcut-keys, application-switcher, window-management

When I use <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> to cycle through my apps I would like to have icons for all my open browsers. I use the <kbd>`</kbd> (Grave or the key above <kbd>TAB</kbd>) but I really find that hard to use.

Anyway I can just use <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> only?

Comment: if you hold on the browser it opens up to your open windows.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I revert Alt-tab behavior to switch between windows on the current workspace?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/68151/how-do-i-revert-alt-tab-behavior-to-switch-between-windows-on-the-current-worksp)

Comment: I don't like to install things for little configurations, in this question there are some way to switch that makes this way of switching comfortable https://askubuntu.com/questions/123977/how-to-ungroup-windows-on-task-switcher

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Here is my solution:

1. Install `compizconfig-settings-manager` and open it (type `ccsm` in terminal).
2. Go to Desktop > Ubuntu Unity Plugin.
3. Open Switcher tab and make `key to start the switcher` and `key to start the switcher in reverse` disabled.
4. Go back to CompizConfig Settings Manager.
5. Go to Window Management and enable Application Switcher.
6. Open Application Switcher and change key bindings of "Next Window (All windows)" to Alt-Tab and "Prev window (All windows)" to Shift-Alt-Tab.

Then you will start to use a different switcher instead of Unity's switcher.

Comment: The application switcher seems gone in Ubuntu 12.10.

Comment: Worked for me in 12.10

Comment: You have to install compiz-plugins in Ubuntu 12.10

Comment: Worked for me on 13.04, too.

Comment: `Window Management` seems not present in 14.04

Comment: using 14.04 and can not do

Comment: @PierredeLESPINAY: See answer below: http://askubuntu.com/a/512640/216010

Comment: Type `ccsm` in terminal to run compizconfig-settings-manager

Comment: I am frustrated by this, especially for browser. I usually have 4-5 browser windows open which I switch between pretty frequently. Here each time I have to switch I have to wait half a second on browser icon in switcher which then shows all browser windows which I can then switch between. Windows does this straight. And I am surprised I have to follow so many steps and in fact install another software for a basic feature which should have been properly implemented in OS itself.

Comment: 18.10, nothing like that. I wonder who thought this annoying, non standard behaviour would be a good idea...

Answer (score 23):

The other option -which I'm testing out this week- is to have the ALT+TAB switch between apps, and ALT+| switch between windows of the same app. It sounds complicated but it works surprisingly well.

Use case A: You're on Firefox and want to switch to Thunderbird: ALT+TAB.

Use case B: You're on a Calc window and want to switch to another Calc window: ALT+|.

In B, you could use the old way of ALT+TAB, where it cycles through all your windows, but it can take a while to do that if you have more than a few windows open. With this thing, you always know where you want to go, and choose the quicker way to get there.

I choose | because it's just above TAB, so my brain and my finger don't need to move very far.

To enable this: System Settings > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Navigation > Switch windows of an application (it's just underneath Switch applications, which is how I found it).

Easy to test, safe, easy to revert, no need to install anything.

Comment: The same behaviour seems enabled by default with ALT + the key between ESC and TAB (which is ² for AZERTY layout), at least in 14.04.

Comment: On my system, the within-app switching key is Alt-`.

Answer (score 18):

Just thought I would share this since I tried to follow the accepted answer but couldn't find the Ubuntu Unity switcher.  I'm running 18.04 and I was able to change the alt-tab behavior by:

1. going to settings->devices->keyboard
2. scroll down to the shortcut for "Switch Windows" (under the "Navigation" section)
3. change the shortcut for Switch Windows to alt-tab

This will overwrite the shortcut for "Switch Applications" which is the default behavior for alt-tab

Comment: That's because Ubuntu 18.04 uses GNOME instead of Unity. You need to follow this Q&A instead: https://askubuntu.com/q/747541/480481

Comment: This is what i needed for 18.04, thanks a million

Comment: Gnome 3.38.2 here. I'm glad I found this answer; I think it's now the best answer to the question. When you change it to use Switch Windows, it even pops up a dialog box warning you that this will disable the Switch Applications functionality. Which is precisely what we want it to do

Answer (score 12):

Before installing anything, try these key combinations:

- <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>|</kbd> (the key above <kbd>Tab</kbd>, may be <kbd>`</kbd>, <kbd>º</kbd>, <kbd>|</kbd>...) to switch between instances of the current application
- <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>ESC</kbd> to direct switch to the next window
- <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>, of course, to switch between different applications

You can see the three keys are neighbors.

Comment: The idea of the original question is not to use the "new" way of alt tabbing. I get  cramp in my fingers when i do these combos.

Comment: non-standard, weird, not intuitive combos...

Answer (score 7):

Otuzbesli's answer works but for Ubunut 14.04 you need to install compiz-plugins in addition to compizconfig-settings-manager

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager compiz-plugins
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 running the Gnome shell. I installed Gnome Tweaks via

```
sudo apt install gnome-tweak-tool
```

and went to

> Extensions -> AlternateTab

and switched the toggle to "On".
This changed the window-switcher to not group by application.

Comment: The question is for Unity, your answer apply to GNOME Shell (Ubuntu 17.10+). The corresponding question is [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/747541/how-do-i-easily-switch-between-windows-rather-than-applications-with-alttab-in).

Comment: @PabloBianchi Oh, I didn't notice that. This post is the first google result if you search for "ubuntu alt+tab", so I assumed it was the right place.

Answer (score 1):

I tried this and as soon as I launched ccsm:

- my desktop was gone. No start menu, taskbar, launcher.. Just the wallpaper.
- `Alt+Tab` doesn't work at all.

I was able to launch a Terminal using right click on desktop. Many people faced this under different situations. Solution always said reset `compiz` config, delete `x11` config, delete `gnome` config and launch unity with `setsid unit && unit`.

For me it said:

```
(0)kash@Laptop$ setsid unity
setsid: failed to execute unity: No such file or directory
(0)kash@Laptop$
```

They also said launch `ccsm` again and enable Unity plugin there. Well, it just wasn't there in the list of enabled or disabled plugins.

Many heart attacks later

```
sudo apt-get install unity
unity
```

I hate the dev who made `ccsm`.

After you install Unity, when you launch `ccsm`, it has Unity plugin in it.

I had Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS running inside a VirtualBox with Windows 10 Host.

Comment: @mmKALLL looks like a link to this question.

Comment: I just hit this myself... For reference, here is an Ask Ubuntu answer documenting variations of the process required, along with more details; https://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears
(thanks @Kashyap)

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu 19 just install

```
sudo apt install compizconfig-settings-manager compiz-plugins
```

and then open compizconfig settings manager

```
ccsm
```

Go to windows management on left sidebar > then select Application Switcher
then just enable Application Switcher from left sidebar.

And that it, when you use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> now you will see application not grouped in <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> dialog.