# How do I easily switch between windows rather than applications in GNOME Shell?

Tags: shortcut-keys, window, application-switcher, gnome-shell

Currently if I hold <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>TAB</kbd> and then while still holding down <kbd>ALT</kbd> I press <kbd>TAB</kbd> I am able to go between applications in a little view and then when I release all the keys that application and all its windows come to the front. 
And this is very useful, but I would like to know if there is a way of switching between individual windows with this keyboard shortcut in the same way rather than grouping windows with an application to switch to?

I am running Ubuntu GNOME 15.10 with GNOME 3.18.

Comment: Just a note: Unity desktop has this feature by default.

Comment: I still can't believe that Gnome broke AltTab.

Comment: Define a custom keyboard shortcut: alt-tab -> switch-window. No extensions required.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

[Alternatetab](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/15/alternatetab/) is just the Extension you were looking for!

Follow the `Managing Extensions` instructions [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/757326/364819) in order to activate it (you should read the text before that section too though). As it is a pre-installed Extensions you will only need to activate it (unless you have removed it, in which case you will need to follow the `Installing a new Extension` section).

So now upon pressing <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>TAB</kbd> and then pressing <kbd>TAB</kbd> without letting go of <kbd>ALT</kbd> (until you have selected the window you want to switch to - then simply release both keys and it will put that window on top) you should be able to switch between individual windows as opposed to applications!

[image: Alternatetab in action]

Comment: You might want to add that the direct web installer option only works from Firefox. Chrome/Chromium (at least for me) shows a message saying a running copy of GNOME cannot be found.

Comment: @Zacharee1: Is the GNOME sort of integrations plugin not installed and activated in those browsers then?

Comment: I'm not sure. I just know that on Chrome, the website can't detect if GNOME is running. I would guess it's because Firefox comes with a lot of Linux distros, and scripts that do that sort of detection tend to work differently in Firefox and Chrome

Comment: @Zacharee1: The website itself does not do the detection, it is an plug-in installed by default called `Gnome Shell Integration`, so if that's not installed in Chrome it won't work.

Comment: Oh, well, yeah it isn't installed in Chrome :p. I was wondering how exactly it was done.

Comment: Installing AlternateTab through the Ubuntu Store made it work flawlessly.

Comment: The extension is now deprecated. There is a video in the extension page and also this answer here describes a more easier way. https://askubuntu.com/a/1154780/970836

Answer (score 93):

You can use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> (the key above <kbd>Tab</kbd>) to cycle between windows of the same application.

You can even mix <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to cycle between application and  <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> to cycle between windows of the selected application.

There is an exposition of the rationale in  [this blog post from Canonical's Didier Roche](https://didrocks.fr/2017/09/14/ubuntu-gnome-shell-in-artful-day-12/). It's part of a series discussing the development of gnome integration in Ubuntu 17.10.

Comment: This works very nicely on MATE. Just mentioning, because it seems the behaviour on GNOME is not as clean. But I get an application-window-only switcher with this combination, exactly as I'd expect

Comment: You wrote "This works very nicely on MATE". What do you mean with "nice"? Do you mean Alt+TAB switches between windows? My usecase:  I want to switch between two terminals with Alt+TAB. I don't want a work-around. I want Alt+TAB.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work on non-Us keyboards...

Comment: awfull design choice, quote is all over the place when it comes to international keyboard...

Comment: Remember that you can define a custom keyboard shortcut to remap the switch-windows action from alt-` to alt-tab (as described in an answer further down this page)

Answer (score 29):

As someone still quite new to Ubuntu, I found the other answers confusing. After a bit of digging I found a simpler solution, as I also want <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> to toggle through all the open windows, not just through the open applications.

In Ubuntu 18.04, you just need to go the Keyboard settings as shown here
 [image: Keyboard settings]

Then set **Switch windows** to <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>. It will automatically disable **Switch applications** which is assigned that key combination by default.

No extra software required.

Comment: This is *great*. In my version of Gnome, I can only use this GUI to map "switch-windows", not "switch-windows-backwards", which is automatically assigned to shift-alt-tab when I do this. This triple-key combo is hard to press, so I like mapping  shift-windows-backwards to alt-<key-above-tab>. One can do this using the gsettings commands mentioned @pomsky's answer.

Answer (score 19):

You may use <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>esc</kbd> combination.

It's not as aesthetically pleasing as <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd>, it doesn't show the overlay with application icons/windows. But it does the job, it just switches to the next window and so on.

Comment: not the thing I want but very nice to know `alt esc`, it's good!

Comment: There is also no way to abort it (like you can<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> by pressing <kbd>esc</kbd>), which can get very annoying.

Comment: Yes, it seems there is no way to abort it, but you can also switch in the reverse direction by pressing <Alt><Shift><Esc>.

Answer (score 8):

This behavior may also be achieved *without* a GNOME extension. I have found a [similar question at Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/394376/how-to-prevent-gnome-shells-alttab-from-grouping-windows-from-similar-apps) that points out how to set the proper GNOME key bindings.

To do it using `gsettings`:

```
$ gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-windows "['<Alt>Tab']"
$ gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-windows-backward "['<Shift><Alt>Tab']"
$ gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-applications "['<Super>Tab']"
$ gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-applications-backward "['<Shift><Super>Tab']"
```

Using the code above when you press <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> you'll switch between windows, while pressing <kbd>SUPER</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> will get you to switch applications.

---

`dconf-editor` allows the same with a graphical interface.

Comment: I was using this solution and it was working great until today. It seems like a gnome update screw it. Now alt+tab only displays the windows from the latest application I used alt+\`. It is quite strange because I even have alt+\` disabled on gsettings. I was avoiding to move to Mint+Cinnamon, but this is the last piece of gnome annoyance I could tolerate. I enjoy gnome shell usability, but it is just too unstable for professional use.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>alt</kbd> <kbd>tab</kbd> - <kbd>down-arrow</kbd> is the way for me.

For example, if I have multiple terminal windows, after pressing <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>tab</kbd> if I then press <kbd>arrow down</kbd> I get the various windows to pick from with <kbd><-</kbd> and <kbd>-></kbd> arrow keys.

[image]

[image]