# How to disable window grouping while Alt-TAB?

Tags: 16.04, application-switcher

How to disable window grouping while Alt-TAB?

Comment: Unity or GNOME? Screenshot?

Comment: In Unity, if you keep holding down `Alt` and press `Tab`, the application switcher opens and shows you a list of application icons. If multiple windows of one application are open on the current workspace, those will be grouped to the same icon, with some small white arrows to indicate the number. By pressing `Tab` repeatedly you can cycle through the icons. If you wait on a grouped icon for more than about half a second, it will expand and show the individual windows instead.

Comment: You could also use window spreading with `Super`+`W`, showing you a small preview of all open windows through which you can cycle with `Tab` and focus the highlighted one with `Enter`.

Comment: For Gnome, you might want to have a look at https://askubuntu.com/q/747541/367990

Comment: @ByteCommander cool, but I don't need this (and don't know who does). I need to disable grouping at all, just 1D list of windows to switch between. No groups.

Comment: @heynnema I don't know; how to determine? I just made fresh installation of `Ubuntu`. They didn't have word `Unity` in installer, I checked `Ubuntu desktop`.

Comment: @ByteCommander I don't need preview either. Plain 1D Alt-Tab allows to switch blindly. This is more comfortable then explore miniature previews.

Comment: @Redbob "duplicated" question was asked 6 years ago and entitled with 11.10 version of Ubuntu. I can't accept it.

Comment: @Dims The accepted answer to the linked duplicate question still applies. Just the labels for the Unity application switcher shortcuts changed slightly.