# How do I make alt + tab cycle through individual windows only in current workspace in GNOME 3?

Tags: gnome, workspaces, gnome-shell, window-manager, application-switcher

I just tried GNOME for the first time and noticed that <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> does not cycle through individual windows, but rather by application. In addition, it cycles through all open applications instead of just the applications in the scope of my current workspace.

How can I get <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> behavior that is similar to XFCE, where <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> cycles through all the individual windows, limited to the scope of the current workspace?

I noticed that if I press the <kbd>super</kbd>, I *sort of* get this behavior, where all the windows of the current workspace are presented to me. But after pressing the super, inexplicably I have to press <kbd>↓</kbd> before I can cycle through the windows, which is  really weird.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Force alt + tab to switch only on current workspace in GNOME shell](https://askubuntu.com/questions/464946/force-alt-tab-to-switch-only-on-current-workspace-in-gnome-shell) && https://askubuntu.com/questions/747541/how-do-i-easily-switch-between-windows-rather-than-applications-with-alttab-in

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might want to use [AlternateTab](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/15/alternatetab/) extension. This extension lets you

> Substitute Alt-Tab with a window based switcher that does not group by application.

Also in the extension settings you'll find an option to enable/disable showing windows only from the current workspace.
[image]

Comment: Add that to the list of extensions that need to be installed out of then box to make gnome usable....

Comment: I am using Ubuntu GNOME 16.04. Are you saying this extension is already installed and it is just a matter of enabling it somehow?

Comment: @ScottF I believe so, open **Tweak Tool** and navigate to **Extensions**, then see if you can find it there. If not you can install from the link in my answer.