# Can't move windows to another workspace anymore

Tags: shortcut-keys, 17.10, workspaces

I have always moved the window to another workspace using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>ArrowKey</kbd>.

But now with Ubuntu 17.10 I can't do this. And the worse part is, <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> is tabbing through all the windows not just the windows open in this workspace.

I have compiz, I have tweaktools, I have tested all combinations from its documents, I have asked in #ubuntu `irc` channel, nothing seems to be working.

Comment: I don't know about the `Alt+Tab` issue - however your key combination to move windows through workspaces can be altered and changed in the keyboard settings. It's originally `Super+Shift+PageUp/Down`. (Like @Pomsky mentioned in one of the answers)

Answer (score 1):

You can install [this extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/310/alt-tab-workspace/) to enable this.

NOTE:

Before you install the extension, you will need to install the [GNOME Shell integration](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeShellIntegrationForChrome/Installation) for your web browser and you will need to install the `chrome-gnome-shell` package using `sudo apt install chrome-gnome-shell`

Then you need to flip the switch in the top right corner of [this](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/310/alt-tab-workspace/) webpage.

To answer the first part: `ctrl-alt-shift` + `up/down` works, but left and right don't

Comment: chrome is the name of the package or is that for chromium? i only use firefox.

Comment: I think that the package should still work

Answer (score 1):

You may use <kbd>super</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>page up</kbd>/<kbd>page down</kbd> key combinations to move windows to workspace above/below  ([Source](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/shell-workspaces-movewindow.html)).

For the second part of the question see this: [How do I make alt + tab cycle through individual windows only in current workspace in GNOME 3?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/957045/how-do-i-make-alt-tab-cycle-through-individual-windows-only-in-current-workspa)

Comment: super key is windows key, but it doesn't move the windows.

Comment: @senaps Tough luck! Works fine for me. Also [official GNOME documentation](https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-help/stable/shell-workspaces-movewindow.html.en) says it should work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70124/discussion-between-pomsky-and-yamboy1).