# Change the alt-tab behavior

Tags: gnome-shell, application-switcher

I found this question ([How do I easily switch between windows rather than applications with ALT+TAB in GNOME?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/747541/how-do-i-easily-switch-between-windows-rather-than-applications-with-alttab-in)) and it's better than nothing, but I'd like to be able to set the behavior of alt-tab the way I want it. Is there such a setting in gnome-shell?

What I would like is just to change the start of the alt-tab behavior to the last used windows whether it is in a different or the current app and that selecting the current app, will **SWITCH** to the last used window not ~switch~ to the current window.

Comment: I tryed "compiz-config settings manager", but it does not seam affect anything ?

Comment: There's a new answer in the question you linked to which fully solves the issue. Basically, use the dconf-editor (or gsettings if you want a command line version) and modify the assigned keys for switch-applications, so that doesn't use <Alt>-tab, and for switch-windows so that it is enabled, and uses <Alt>-tab. Simple, and restores the behavior of Ubuntu 16.04 which is what I think you're after. Not sure what order the windows come up in though which seems like it might be part of your goal.

Comment: Thanks Toby, that seem good, but what I was ultimately looking for is to use the new gnome shell behavior, just not if I simply press alt tab and release it, which mean I want to get me to the last used window. If I hold alt, it's cause I'm searching for a specific window and gnome new behavior seems fine in that case.