# Ring switcher is not automatically selecting the windows on key release

Tags: compiz, application-switcher, workspace-switcher

I configured the ring switcher with the CCSM.

I press <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> and I start to cycle between all windows, but when I release the keys on the desired one, I have to either click on it or press enter.

How can I make it automatically select the window when I release the key?

It was working, but suddenly it stopped doing it.

I have the same trouble with Shift-Switcher compiz plugin.

Comment: Seeing this problem too with 12.04. I disabled the builtin Unity switcher in favor of the good 'ol Ring Switcher, however it doesn't have the same old behavior as it did before.                                                   I followed [these general steps](http://askubuntu.com/a/68880/19264) to use Ring Switcher instead

Answer (score 5):

I guess I just figured it out!

Both Ring and Shift Switcher, in Ubuntu, use <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> by default instead of <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> so they don't conflict with Untity's Switcher. So far, so good...

The problem is... <kbd>Super</kbd> alone is used in Unity to show the Launcher! So when you <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>, then release <kbd>Tab</kbd> (or let both pressed for a while), <kbd>Super</kbd> will trigger the launcher and "steal" the focus away from the ring/shift switcher, so they won't detect they key release and thus not will not select the current window.

And there are 2 solutions to solve the conflict. You either:

- Disable Unity's `Key to show the Launcher`, or remap it away from <kbd>Super</kbd>

or

- Set Shift (or Ring) Switcher to use a different combination other than <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>, something that does not use <kbd>Super</kbd>.
- An obvious combo would be <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> itself, provided you also disable *all* `Key to start the switcher...` key bindings in Unity's Switcher settings. Or, as a "sweet revenge", map *them* to use <kbd>Super</kbd> instead of <kbd>Alt</kbd> :P

Personally I prefer the latter, since tapping <kbd>Super</kbd> to open the dash is *very* useful, and there is no other dead key so easily available for that.

I can provide some screenshots to help if anyone finds this useful.