# How to make the shift switcher select the window after I release the key

Tags: unity, compiz, window-manager

I use Shift Switcher to surf through the open windows and select the desired one. I've configured the combinations so that they don't conflict with others. Mainly I use the *next window*, <kbd>**Super**</kbd> + <kbd>**Q**</kbd> and *previous window*,<kbd>**Super**</kbd> + <kbd>**Shift**</kbd> + <kbd>**Q**</kbd> switches. But release the keys (or the <kbd>**Super**</kbd> key) does not make the selected window active; I have to hit the modifier keys like <kbd>**Return**</kbd>, <kbd>**Shift**</kbd>, <kbd>**Alt**</kbd>, etc. or click with the mouse pointer for both switcher modes (*Cover/Flip*). But I'd like the selected window getting activated right when I release the button, similar to what we have with the <kbd>**Alt**</kbd> + <kbd>**Tab**</kbd> switching.

[image: snap1a]
*(flip mode shift switch)*

[image: snap1b]
*(cover mode shift switch)*

Here's a snapshot of my key combinations for the *Window Management* option in **CompizConfig Settings Manager**:

[image: snap2]

Comment: I don't exactly remember, but most possibly you have to disable a settings in unity for disabling that `super` key binding. Again I don't remember exactly, so I will let you know if I find the exact setting. I got it by googling.

Comment: Yeah, most possibly this is the issue - [Ring switcher is not automatically selecting the windows on key release](http://askubuntu.com/q/124087) . Don't use `super` or remap `super` in unity.

Comment: @Web-E, thanks for the link... it was helpful and got the problem fixed..