# Eclipse disappearing from unity / alt-tab in 12.04

Tags: 12.04, eclipse

Eclipse is randomly disappearing from the left panel and from alt-tab after a few minutes of use for me in 12.04.

It's definitely still there; if I minimize whatever window I have on top of it, I can get back to it... but that's the only way.  If I minimize it, I'm doomed and have no way to get the window back.

Any idea on how to fix this?

Alternatively, any idea of a workaround (e.g. some way to either re-raise the window from the commandline, or force unity/alt-tab to pick it back up)?

Comment: Anything like this thread... [Eclipse/PyDev not showing up correctly][1]


  [1]: http://askubuntu.com/questions/130864/eclipse-pydev-not-showing-up-correctly

Comment: this is a known bug with java software and unity.  if you use eclipse from repo, it just works(at least for me).

Comment: I have the same issue