# Icon for alt-tab/application switcher

Tags: unity, application-switcher

I'm trying to get my program to install correctly, and it mostly does, the launcher icon looks fine, and it opens fine, but the icon used in the alt-tab/app switcher doesn't show up.

The .desktop file points to the correct location for the applications image, hence the launcher icon working, but the alt-tab icon doesn't show up...

Here is the problem in image form:

[image]

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: What desktop environment are you using? The switcher on the photo looks decent and I want it, too! (Compiz has only s***.)

Comment: Hey, I believe I was using Unity 2d at the time. Hope this helps :)

Comment: Well... Unity 2d is gone.

Comment: yep, I was on 12.04 at the time, this may help though:

http://askubuntu.com/questions/68151/how-do-i-revert-alt-tab-behavior-to-switch-between-windows-on-the-current-worksp/68171#68171

Comment: No, it doesn’t help, as any switcher suggested there has huge icons for each application. Unity 2d ran with metacity, by the way. And I am on 12.04, but not for long, I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it!

Change the relative path to an absolute path in your pyqt4 designer code.

for example, change from:

icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(_fromUtf8("../liumimages/path3194.png")), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)

to:

icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(_fromUtf8("/home/ikt/code/yaum/liumimages/path3194.png")), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)

Done!

Comment: what file text did you change to achieve this?