# Is there a way to change so that Alt + tab will work similar to windows?

Tags: unity

When I open multiple terminal sessions and the sessions are buried under one application and I have to press ctrl + ` to move between the same application.

Is there a way to change so that Alt + tab will work similar to windows?

Answer (score 0):

Install compizconfig-settings-manager with `sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager` from a terminal or search for it in the software center. It allows you to alter the behavior of alt+tab, among other things.

Answered here: [How do I revert Alt-tab behavior to switch between windows on the current workspace?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68151/how-do-i-revert-alt-tab-behavior-to-switch-between-windows-on-the-current-worksp)

(just flagged question as duplicate)