# Switch between windows within workspace: difference between 16.04 and 18.04?

Tags: unity, gnome, workspaces

I am confused with changes in 18 04 with windows switching in presence of multiple workspaces. Imagine that I have an application (say terminal) open in two different workspaces. Now using `alt+tab` and choosing the application seems to have different behaviours:

- ubuntu 16.04: go to application within the same workspace
- ubuntu 18.04: go to application but in the workspace where it was last used.

Is this correct? If yes, is there any chance I can revert to the 16.04 like behaviour?

Thanks!!

PS: technically, this is a duplicate of this [2011 post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68151/how-do-i-revert-alt-tab-behavior-to-switch-between-windows-on-the-current-worksp) on Ubuntu 11.04, it seems old enough that a new answer is welcome?

Comment: indeed,  I missed that post, sorry!